# Deprecated codes in IOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm pretty new to ios and Objective-c and I got this warning from xcode and don't know exactly what to do with it.

willRotateToInterface also not working and I also checked the other questions here but it's only having the same way to apply it.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
     UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                      categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}
```

I got the warning registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0 - Use -[UIApplication registerForRemoteNotifications] and UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter requestAuthorizationWithOptions:completionHandler:]

Comment: The yellow background message has already told you what need to do. Just replace the method to the new one.

Comment: @YunCHEN yeah but I don't know exactly the value I should put on it since I'm pretty new to ios

Comment: Press `control`+`command`, then click the method, you will get into the .h file of method declarations. You will find more detail in that .h file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly implement the below method

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{   
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
    {
        //..... Your code here
    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
    { 

    }];

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```